# WiX - compare String with <property> in <?if ?> <? else ?> statement

Tags: properties, wix

Hey Guys hopefully somebody could help me with this problem. I am trying to compare the value of an Property with an String which is manually defined.
I am not sure if it should work like this here is my Code.

```
    <Variable Name="VS2013Installed" />
    <Variable Name="VS2015Installed" />

<!-- Should Search the Registry for the Keys  -->  

<!-- Searches for the Key of Visual Studio 2013 -->    
<Property Id="VS2013" Secure="yes" >    
      <RegistrySearch Id="SEARCH_VS2010" Type="raw" Root="HKCR" Key="VisualStudio.accessor.12.0\shell\Open\ddeexec\Application" >        
      </RegistrySearch>                    
    </Property>

<!-- Searches for the Key of Visual Studio 2015 -->
    <Property Id="VS2015" Secure="yes" >
      <RegistrySearch Id="SEARCH_VS2015" Type="raw" Root="HKCR" Key="VisualStudio.accessor.14.0\shell\Open\ddeexec\Application" >
      </RegistrySearch>
    </Property>

<!-- Should compare the value of the property with the String-->
    <?if [VS2013] = "VisualStudio.12.0" ?>
      <?define VS2013Installed= "1" ?>
    <?else ?>
      <?define VS2013Installed= "0" ?>
    <?endif?>

<!-- Should compare the value of the property with the String-->
    <?if [VS2015] = "VisualStudio.14.0" ?>
      <?define VS2015Installed= "1" ?>
    <?else ?>
      <?define VS2015Installed= "0" ?>
    <?endif?>

<!-- This Condition is only here to get an Message Window with the values of the variables-->
    <Condition Message="$(var.VS2013Installed)$(var.VS2015Installed)">
          <![CDATA[0 = 1 ]]>       
    </Condition>
```

As a result of the Condition I am getting: 0,0

Comment: How are you going to use knowledge of which Visual Studio versions are installed? In the Condition child of Features, perhaps? Please [edit] your question to show this.

Comment: I put some comments into the code. My Problem is that [VS2013] = "VisualStudio.12" in the "if else statement" returns 0. I Also tested the value of VS2015 and it contains "VisualStudio.12".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiX conditional compilation is for WiX variables. You want conditions on Windows Installer properties. It looks like you have a handle on setting properties and using property expressions; just make it all properties and conditions. (Your use of WiX `define` and `var` is fine, though.)

---

You are using the WiX Toolset to build a Windows Installer package (.msi file). A Windows Installer package is a relational database as you can see visually with tools like [InstEd](http://www.instedit.com/scrn_main2.png). The Windows Installer engine (msiexec) uses the database to perform standard and custom actions for an operation (install, repair, uninstall, etc) on a product. Actions can set, pass and retrieve data via Windows Installer properties. A property is usually referenced via its name in square brackets, e.g., `[VS2015]`. Except for WiX-provided custom action (they you might or might not use), everything that is happens at install-time is Windows Installer.

WiX variables are simply a way of avoiding repetition in your WiX source. They are "compiled away" when WiX builds the package. So, their values are fixed. WiX's conditional compilation (define, if, etc) are also compiled away at build-time.

In your code, it seems you expect to use a property value in a conditional compilation statement. Property values are not set until msiexec runs. So, you have find another way of using the information you are gathering with registry search. One way might be, if you have a Feature that supports VS2015 and another that supports 2013, is to enable or disable features based on expressions that reference the property values.

Comment: Thank you very much. The condition in features was the solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect which versions of Visual Studio are installed then look at the WiX-supplied WixVSExtension and just use the properties it supplies.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixvsextension.html

and it does include VS 2013 and 2015.

Comment: A handy example of its usage is in the [setup](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/Setup/VotiveMsi) for WiX itself.